# Spinner adapter Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, android-spinner

This issue is a weird one so please try to bear with me.

I have manually ported an Android project from Android Studio 1.3.2 to Eclipse Mars 4.5.0.

Following this (seemingly successful) port, i am faced with the following problem:
My custom spinner adapters have stopped working.

This is the piece of code where the failure happens in the custom spinner adapter:

```
 @Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, null);
    }
    TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_text);
    label.setText(getItem(position).getName());

    return label;
}
```

When running the debugger, no individual statement fails. Inspecting the *label* variable, the text is set, all is fine and dandy. However, when the function ends, i get this stack trace:

```
    09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650): Process: com.example.objectives, PID: 5650
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:8014)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4864)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4717)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4692)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.example.objectives.adapters.StageSpinnerAdapter.getDropDownView(StageSpinnerAdapter.java:44)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(AppCompatSpinner.java:624)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(AppCompatSpinner.java:620)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.measureHeightOfChildrenCompat(ListViewCompat.java:290)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1200)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:584)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.show(AppCompatSpinner.java:766)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.performClick(AppCompatSpinner.java:424)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
09-07 15:14:57.888: E/AndroidRuntime(5650):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Ok so **the actual problem** is this:
This error appears **only** in Eclipse, not Android Studio.

Other details that i think may be useful:
MinSdk: 15, targetSdk: 23, maxSdk: 23;

I will post any and all other details that might be needed.

Many thanks.

Edit: 
Line 44 is:

```
label.setText(getItem(position).getName());
```

Comment: Don't you have to return view instead of label?

Comment: What is line 44? Did you try to return the convertView instead of the label?

Comment: why you returning label instead convertView?

Comment: Will try returning the convertview and update the question. Odd since this was not a problem with Android Studio.

Comment: Returning convertView does not fix the problem sadly...

Comment: *I have manually ported an Android project from Android Studio 1.3.2 to Eclipse Mars 4.5.0* why would you do that? eclipse is not supported by android anymore

Comment: is `getItem(position).getName()` returning any thing? As Tim said, why are migrating to Eclipse. Plus try adding padding to your label.

Comment: Porting to eclipse is an unfortunate requirement that is out of my control. getItem(position).getName() returns correctly, as i said, inspecting the label variable reveals it's text to be set correctly. I am using google's spinner_dropdown_item layout so i assume that no padding is required

Answer (score 0):

I think its related to the " convertView "
in here:

```
if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, null);
    }
TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_text);
```

the textview label you get its actually coming from a previous convertView,

if you get rid of the null checking for convertView and create a new convertView it will be fine